# react-native-router-flux: Jump to specific scene and refresh it

Tags: react-native-router-flux

Version

Tell us which versions you are using:

react-native-router-flux v3.40.1 (v3 is not supported)
react-native v0.46.4
Expected behaviour

When I press button, What I expected to go to the specific page and refresh it.

When I use Actions.home({ type: ActionConst.RESET}), it actually go to the home page, but doesn't refresh.

When I use Actions.home({ type:ActionConst.REPLACE}), it go to the home page and refresh it. But When I trigger some actions to refresh the home page again, I will send multiple requests to the backend. I found the issue, it's caused by 'REPLACE', which will keep the old home component in the stack. When I refresh it, it will make all home components refreshed.

Can you help me how to resolve it? I want to go the home page and refresh it and keep only one home component in the stack.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Actions.popTo('yourPage')

and add a callback  function 
like your props.apply();

and add a function where you have clcked that will be called when page gets apply() function.